# Create-react-app deployment failure on Dokku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, dokku

I'm trying to deploy a fresh React app made via [Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to my Dokku on DigitalOcean thank to [this heroku buildpacks](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack). Following their instructions it ends up failing ...

```
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
=====> Detected Framework: Static HTML
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote: 100  838k  100  838k    0     0   514k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  514k
-----> Installed directory to /app/bin
       Using release configuration from last framework (Static HTML).
remote: cat: /tmp/build/last_pack_release.out: input file is output file
--- {}
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types ->
-----> Releasing justpushit-app (dokku/justpushit-app:latest)...
-----> Deploying justpushit-app (dokku/justpushit-app:latest)...
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.predeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/justpushit-app/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file found (/home/dokku/justpushit-app/DOKKU_SCALE)
=====> web=1
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> justpushit-app web container output:
       Injecting runtime env into /app/build/static/js/main.060925d8.js (from .profile.d/inject_react_app_env.sh)
       setuidgid: usage: setuidgid account child
=====> end justpushit-app web container output
To pantouflesdokku:justpushit-app
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@pantouflesdokku:justpushit-app'
```

**Everything seems to work fine but the app is never launched. What am I missing here ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was fairly simple**. The whole build works but the application must be initialized somehow.

I added a `Procfile` and wrote the following line in it ...

```
web: npm start
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm having the same problem you're having and found your question when I was looking for a fix. I'm just not 100% sure about your solution. I think `npm start` starts a development server, which is not suitable for production use. The result of the build pack is just a static site, so I can not image you have to run a npm command.

Comment: I actually had the exact same error but with EmberJS and searched for 2 days to .. fall on my own solved issue. Yes, I don't think it's good for production, it's not even working for this framework anyway, have you found a good solution ?

Comment: Hi! can I ask your steps to deploy create react app on dokku? I've added the buildpack and it fails at build stage.
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/issues/162

Answer (score 1):

Because I had the same problem I opened an issue for this specific build pack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/issues/54 And luckily it's maintainer was kind enough to provide me with the correct `Procfile` content.

To fix this problem you should have a `Procfile` with the following line:

`web: bin/boot`

Instead of `web: npm start` this won't spawn a complete development server. So it should be a lot easier on your server's memory/cpu usage.